# Year and Personnel of Undercover girl blues

Tags: jazz

Does anyone know when "Undercover Girl Blues" by Lester Young was recorded? Here is a link to the song:

http://youtu.be/k2IhiX1re7A

To me, it sounds like "Kansas City". So, can we guess this song was recorded during the 30s? Also, what is the personnel for this particular song?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [JazzDisco.org](http://jazzdisco.org), specifically the [1951 Verve recordings page](http://www.jazzdisco.org/verve-records/discography-1951/), "Undercover Girl Blues" was recorded on January 16th, 1951, and the personnel on the recording was:

- Saxophone: Lester Young
- Piano: John Lewis
- Bass: Gene Ramsey
- Drums: Jo Jones

My guess is that the information on JazzDisco.org is gleaned from [The Complete Lester Young Studio Recordings on Verve](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000296VH), though I do not own that box set and thus cannot confirm. However, that site is general accurate in my experience, meaning that I have yet to find anything that doesn't match up with other sources while exploring it.